# how to print part of a string in Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist

CODE:

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
String input = in.readLine();
ArrayList<String> massiiv = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
   massiiv.add(input[i]); // error here
```

HI!

How can I split the input and add the input to the data structure massiiv?

For instance, input is: "Where do you live?". Then the massiiv show be:

```
massiv[0] = where
massiv[1] = do
massiv[2] = you
```

THANKS!

Comment: create regex to remove the blacklisted words and then simply split the String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java Documentation is your friend:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

String[] myWords = input.split(" ");

Answer (score 2):

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
String input = in.readLine();

String[] massiiv = input.split(" ");
```

Comment: It should be `String[] splitted...`

Comment: splitted would be a `String[]` not a `String`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`split(String regex)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String[] inputs = in.readLine().split(" "); //split string into array
ArrayList<String> massiiv = new ArrayList();
for (String input : inputs) {
    massiiv.add(inputs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), which allows an application to break a string into tokens.

Use space as delimiter, set the `returnDelims` flag to false such that space only serves to separate tokens. Then

```
     StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("this is a test");
     while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
         System.out.println(st.nextToken());
     }
```

prints the following output:

```
     this
     is
     a
     test
```

Comment: From the Docs: *StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code*

Answer (score 0):

You would use the [string.split()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method in java.  In your case, you want to split on spaces in the string, so your code would be:

```
massiiv = new ArrayList(input.split(" "));
```

If you don't want to have the word `you` in your output, you would have to do additional processing.

Answer (score 0):

A one-line solution. Any amount of whitespace possible between the strings.

```
ArrayList<String> massiiv =  new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(input.split("\\s+")));
```